# How do I gather the people to create a new Stack Exchange community?

Tags: site-growth, stack-exchange

Technically, to create a new Stack Exchange site, there is a procedure on Area51.  This is covered by the question *[How do I create a new community on Stack Exchange?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1490/165)*.

However, since then there have been [changes to the Area51 procedure](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/60896):

> Going forward, we generally expect proposal authors to have the means to see their site ideas through. If you are accustomed to throwing up proposal after proposal hoping somebody ELSE will build your site, Area 51 is not the place to START your community search.

Suppose I don't have any community yet but want to start one, how do I start?

As an example / case study, we might consider the recently failed proposal [Dutch language Q&A](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122507/dutch-language).

One option would be signing up to existing forums to advertise it there, but this would be spammy and probably ineffective.

Comment: It seems to work backwards: you need to build the community first and then have it land in Area 51 to have the Stack site. I tried hard to have he Catalan language Q&A go through, but I could not: trying to get people through SE is forbidden and pinging folks in twitter is a fragile approach.

Comment: @fedorqui This is Community Building Stack Exchange, if anywhere has the experts on how to build a community first it should be here!  If only this site had a bit more activity, my question has 3 views per day...

Comment: The way SE is run now, my impression is that the proposal process through Area51 is pretty much dead. The corporation will decide in it's infinite wisdom.

Comment: If we look at the existing stack exchange sites I would not know the website or organization for all of them. I don't think that any one is in a close relation to one website or organization. I wouldn't want the stack exchange site of a private company anyways. I think this rule is complete nonsense. I would not have an issue with thousands of proposals that nobody commits to existing on area51.

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting question. Some people just start proposal on Area51 thinking or hoping that interested people will find the proposal and join/follow it and eventually proposal will get success but actually things are opposite. Before starting a proposal, you should have sufficient mass committed to participate and contribute to the proposal. only then there are chances for a proposal to pass the definition phase.

Area51 FAQ states:

> How do I start a new site?
>
> ... All we ask is that you have an enthusiastic, committed group of expert users who check in regularly, asking and answering questions.

Seven days of inactivity will lead to closure and removal of the proposal in the definition phase. So, without a solid group ready to participate in Definition phase, proposal is likely to be inviable. That's why Stack Exchange do ask to link organization/group ready to support the proposal:

> [image]

Now coming to the point of question, the way/mode of gathering mass may depend upon the type of community you're going to build e.g whether it's a technological site or cultural site or a site belongs to arts, business etc.

You need to think for gathering and inviting people three times 1. Before making proposal 2. After making the proposal when it is in definition phase 3. When proposal is ready in beta phase

1. Before starting proposal on Area51:

   In this stage you're supposed to have a group of people who gather and meet or talks through social network frequently. Formal discussion, introduction and invitation through mail to people or organization may not work here.

   - It is expected that you have a solid group of people who are in your touch may be whom you know personally or talks daily or at least once in 3 to 4 days. They may be your close friends or family members or colleagues.
   - **Build a group** on social networks (may be Telegram) and do daily conversations regarding the topics of proposal you're going to make.
   - **Invite interested people to your group** and introduce them how are you all are going to start a proposal.
   - If you have a fair connection to particular organization working on field relevant to topic of your proposal, approach it
   - Once road-map is ready and clear to all people in the group, decide and start a proposal. Inform all the members how to join and post example questions.
2. During the definition phase:

   - Bring your proposal to more and more people, make them join your proposal and your group for discussions; you can also think of creating chat-room on Stack Exchange if it works.
   - Help others with joining the proposal and understanding how Area51 staging work, more precisely the definition phase.
   - After your proposal starts looking clear and fine, start approaching organizations and institutions relevant to the domain of your proposal; introduce them about Stack Exchange, your proposal and Area51 process and request them to join or inform/make people belonging to that organization join the proposal
   - Also try your hands in promoting your proposal to those Stack Exchange communities which might be interested in your proposal.
   - Find groups on social network when you can advertise your proposal.
   - Remind all members to vote on example questions occasionally.

I don't know much how commitment phase goes but when you succeed and pass through definition phase and likely also the commitment phase, start thinking on [promoting private beta](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2671/2518) and [public beta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/23/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/).

Keeping enthusiasm and interest among members of your proposal or community is essential to keep your proposal active. Once existing members will start enjoying it, they'll bring others to your proposal.

Comment: that ready pretty much like the area51 FAQ. And it does not answer the question. You don't explain how one can get a "organization or webste" to link to as requested.